# Sefarim explaining R Akiva Eiger on shas

Tags: jewish-books

I recently saw a sefer called Sadeh Eliyahu that goes through the GRA on shas and elaborates what he is saying. I'm wondering if anyone has ever done something similar for R Akiva Eiger's Gilyon hashas.

Comment: Dunno about every גליון השס but משנת רע"א האיר יוסף is dedicated to explicating RAE's Torah

Comment: See in the link under his seforim the different editions that came out elucidated  https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%92%D7%A8